# Copying cells from multiple workbooks to a single worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to extract say column A1:A5 from multiple workbooks and copy it to a single worksheet. Copying each workbook into the adjacent column.

For example:

Workbook one (A1:A5) will copy to Master workbook (A1:A5)
Workbook two (A1:A5) will copy to Master workbook (B1:B:5)

I have this code which sums all the values.

```
Sub SUM_Workbooks()
Dim FileNameXls, f
Dim wb As Workbook, i As Integer
FileNameXls = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files, *.xls*", MultiSelect:=True)

If Not IsArray(FileNameXls) Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each f In FileNameXls
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(f)
Dim rngPaste As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
     Set rngPaste = .Range("A" & .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
End With
rngPaste.Value = wb.Name
wb.Worksheets("Page 3").Range("P18:P22").Copy
rngPaste.Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
Next f

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

What I need is to paste the value from the workbooks into adjacent columns.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
```

To this bit of code:

```
For Each f In FileNameXls
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(f)
    Dim rngPaste as Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
         Set rngPaste = .Range("A" & .columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(,1)
    End With
    rngPaste.Value = wb.Name
    wb.Worksheets("Page 3").Range("P18:P22").Copy
    rngPaste.Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
Next f
```

What this will do is go to the last column each time and then move all the way to left to find the last column with actual data, then offset that by 1 column. In row 1 of that column, the name of the workbook will be entered. The data will be entered starting in row 2.

Comment: Thanks I did as you said but now I don't get any data pulling through in adjacent columns it all get summed at the bottom of column B. 

Just out of interest is it possible to copy the name if each worksheet above the column that was copied?

Comment: @RalphDylan - Are you sure you entered the code exactly as written. I have updated it add the workbook name to the top of the column.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

I am getting an error "object variable or with block variable not set."
For the line rngPaste = .Range(

Comment: @RalphDylan - Apologies. I forgot the `Set` command. Try now.

Comment: No worries. Thanks so much for doing this.

The only thing is for some reason it isn't copying each worksheet out but instead copies to cell B16385 of all places

Comment: @RalphDylan - can you rephrase that please. It's not clear to me what you are saying.

Comment: Sorry. So I manage to fix part of it. I changed the "A" in .Range("A" 

To .Range(A1:A4

However lets say I choose 5 workbooks I need to copy from and I need the results displayed in adjacent columns. So the data from workbook 1 in colmun a and the data from workbook 2 in column b.

Instead what happens now is only the last book i selected is copied. So only workbook 5 is shown in column b

Comment: @RalphDylan - can you edit the current code you are using into your original question. Your issues don't make any sense to me, as the code I wrote will work as you are requesting.

Comment: I have edited the code. I copied straight from exel.

Does it have something to do with the operation:=x1Add

Comment: @RalphDylan - I rejected your edit because I was asking you to edit **your original question**. However, no mind. Yes, it does have to do with the `xlAdd` argument. Remove everything in that line past the `xlPasteValues`. It will work. Also, make sure to keep `.Range("A" & .columns.Count).` instead of what you changed it to.

Comment: HI Scott, thanks for your help. I am still having trouble. 
Not really sure what could be the issue. When I run the macro and select say 3 excel files. It only copies the last pack and copies it into B16384 of all places. Why could this be? I have updated the code to what I am using. Copied straight from yours

Comment: @RalphDylan - I suggest leaving your original code in the question too. And editing the question to include the new code. This way, anyone who comes after can see the problem clearly, as well as the solution (we hope!). I will try to test it more fully a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
.Range("A" & .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft), Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:=True
End With

---

You need to put this between "For" loop in order to extract data from all the excel sheets/workbooks.